# Is it secure for a platform to use the same private key for multiple clients' SSH connections?

Tags: ssh, multi-tenancy

https://nexla.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360053720333-Database-Connection-Options

Specifically:

> In a text editor, add the below public SSH key to the authorized_keys
> file. The key must be all on one line. Make sure that you don’t
> introduce any line breaks when cutting and pasting.

This is the last portion of "Step 1." - this implies each user does not generate their own key, and there is no method to, as there is no where to import a private key within the platform. As far as I can tell this is reusing the same private key for multiple users.

It seems like there is potential for users of the platform to access other user's of the platforms data. Obviously the attacker would  not only have to be a user of the platform but also know the database details post-ssh connection. It would also require the use of the same username (but given a default is suggested, seems likely). There is a lot an attacker would have to know to successfully access data they aren't supposed to, but I thought the rule in security is assume the attacker knows every detail of the set up, and make sure it's still secure (0 trust).

Edit: Hopefully add clarity and retract my statement in my first comment. I'm fairly confident after more research and double checking the phrasing that this is re-using one key per user and not good practice. Would love to see a more reputable (or at least a more security focused engineer than myself) confirm or deny this in an answer.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, can you help me understand why this isn't a good question for the site? I'm not implying it is insecure, just trying to understand....

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm not sure where you are seeing a concern.  The article seems to describe typical SSH public key based authentication.  First, a secure connection is built based on the server's private/public key pair (is this what you mean by same private key for multiple clients?).  Then, clients authenticate using public key authentication, where clients prove possession of the private key associated with the public key stored on the server (each client uses a unique keypair to authenticate, only public keys are stored on the server). Where are you seeing a security concern?

Comment: @mti2935 because each user uses the *same* public key if following that guide. That implies they're setting up their server to connect to the same private key used by the platform for each account attempting to connect, no?

Comment: @mti2935 each client doesn't generate a new key, instead they're instructed "In a text editor, add the below public SSH key to the authorized_keys file. The key must be all on one line. Make sure that you don’t introduce any line breaks when cutting and pasting."

Comment: The authorized_keys file is for Public Keys.  Perhaps the vendor is giving you their public key and asking you to authorize it for access.

Comment: @tjd They are, but given its the same public key for every user, doesn't that necessarily imply it's using the same private key for every user?

Comment: Smells like they're giving a single Private Key access to each user.  Potentially the key belongs to their Support team?  I'd definitely ask the Vendor.

Comment: @tjd I've reached out their support team and will update the question as I learn more.

Comment: @TCooper It looks to me like these instructions allow access to your database from *Nexla's SSH bastion server* (at 34.231.167.112 or 54.209.27.1).  So, it's akin to a web application where a web server is allowed access to a db server.  In both cases, there may be many users accessing the db through another server (either a bastion server in this case, or a web server in the case of a web app). If that's the case, the private key would live on the bastion server, and users that can access the bastion server can access your db, but there would not be a need to give each user the private key.

Comment: @mti2935 the instructions are for connecting *your* external database through *your* bastion server (please see diagram just under first section listing bastion host in "your network"), and are the same for every user. They're asking each user to create a connection to their platform using the same private key. I'm not sure how that isn't obvious at this point (though I've spent more time on this than I probably should)

Comment: @TCooper I was assuming that the server all the way to the left of the diagram (with the Nexla logo) is another bastion server, but it could be any type of server. In any case, I think we are saying the same thing - these instructions simply allow the 'Nexla server' (for lack of a better name) access to your database server, through your bastion server.  But, I don't see why the private key would ever have to leave the Nexla server.  It's simply a tunnel, to reach the database server - not much different than allowing multiple users to access a protected server through a VPN.

Comment: @mti2935 this configuration opens up my protected server to be accessed by the *same* private key that Kim at fake company one has access to through the same platform. That Bob at fake company two has access to through the same platform. That Chloe at fake company three has access to through the same platform, etc. The private key isn't and shouldn't ever leave the server, but there should be a different private key per user

Comment: @TCooper  Yes, this is correct.  If Kim, Bob, and Chloe can access (and authenticate with) the Nexla server, then they can reach your database server through this ssh tunnel.  But, let's assume you have Sue, Steve, and Mary, who are legitimate users that need to access your db.  Wouldn't giving Sue, Steve, and Mary access to your db through this tunnel be better than exposing your database server to the whole world, just so Sue, Steve, and Mary can access it?

Comment: @TCooper  The tunnel just makes it possible for users to *reach* your db server. Presumably, there are more levels of authentication - first at the Nexla server, then secondly at your db server - that any user (legitimate or malicious) would have to complete in order to access any data.

Comment: @mti2935 more levels of authentication doesn't change that providing a single private key for multiple users is bad practice. "Better than nothing" isn't exactly the way I want to secure the data of the businesses I work for. I'd prefer everything done right every step of the way. All this would take is a place in the UI for users to provide their own private key and then they can generate their own public key to match. Rather than rely on key re-use. I won't accept that I'm opening up my **SECURE**  shell to *any* other user of the same platform. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: "Yes, this is correct. If Kim, Bob, and Chloe can access (and authenticate with) the Nexla server, then they can reach your database server through this ssh tunnel." more importantly, in what world is this not a security vulnerability?

Comment: @TCooper, Consider a company with two locations, location A and location B.  The company has a private LAN at A, and a private LAN at B.  Employees at A sometimes need to access servers at B, and vice versa.  So, the network admin creates a VPN between the firewall at A and the firewall at B, using a key pair.  Now, Kim, Bob, and Chloe at location A can access servers at location B.  Are Kim, Bob, and Chloe sharing the same key pair?

Comment: @mti2935 I'm not sure if you know what Nexla is/does? These aren't users from the same company.

Answer (score 1):

The title and the body of your question ask two different things:

1. The title asks whether it is secure to have public key authentication enabled in your ssh server and allow every user on the system to authenticate using the same key pair. That's obviously an *insecure* setup. An example as to why, is that a user can list all other users of the system (e.g. `cat /etc/passwd`) and then just connect to the system as another user.
2. The body of your question describes a different scenario; you ask whether it's secure to:

   - have host A (bastion) run an ssh server
   - have host B run a db server
   - allow access to host B only from host A
   - create a user, with default name nexla, on host A
   - allow public key authentication ssh access on host A
   - set the public key of the user on host A to be a predetermined one
   - announce the public key of the user to the public (no pun intented)
   - have the private key reside on Nexla's servers (not known to the public)

   This is obviously more secure than the scenario described in point 1, because your bastion host is only used by Nexla's data connectors from inside the company's network, the public key cannot be used to figure out the private key (as far as we know) and you have the choice not to use the default user name, making an attack even more difficult for potential attackers. However, it has the problem that the private key to connect to your internal network resides on Nexla's systems (which can be anything from hardened servers to employees' unpatched laptops). This makes it a *trust issue on Nexla's security practices*.

So, I don't see how other customers could abuse your bastion (or the db) without having access to both the private key and the username (if not the default). Even if they do try to use Nexla's web interface in order to break into your db (they can't access the bastion host by using the web interface) they still don't have the credentials to connect to your db - and a manual brute force is practically impossible (remember, they have to use the web interface in order to connect to your db, because they don't have the private key).

But, for the sake of the argument, let's say that they do have access to both the private key and the username you've used for the user at host A (bastion). Having this access means that they will have already broken into Nexla's network or are Nexla's employees with suitable access. So, if they do have access into Nexla's network, won't they also have access to all the data that Nexla is processing on your behalf (i.e. your db)? (*is there a point into breaking into your network afterall, if they have all your data?*)

Answer (score 0):

That's a strong 4096-bit RSA key. I wouldn't worry about the key's cryptographic soundness, but **I would worry about its storage and handling.**

It does not at all fill me with confidence that the comment to this widely-used private key says `avinash@Avinashs-MacBook-Pro-2.local`, implying that it was generated by a user at this company named Avinash on a laptop rather than on a server.

It is best to never copy private keys but rather generate new keys on new hosts and then add them to relevant `authorized_keys` files, then to retire the old key and remove it from those files. However, with a manual model like this, that's not at all practical. There's no revocation mechanism. No way to remove the key's access if it ever gets compromised.

If Avinash's laptop is stolen, the key is out in the wild. If a few years pass and he gets a replacement and the laptop is then sold and the contents are recovered, the key is out in the wild. If Avinash's laptop is backed up and the backup is compromised, the key is out in the wild. If one of the servers the key was copied to was compromised, the key is out in the wild.

If the cryptography behind RSA (or at least RSA at 4096 bytes) is found to be insecure (OpenSSH has already migrated to preferring ed25519 in place of RSA as its preferred key type, but 4096-bit RSA is considered secure at the moment), an attacker may be able to authenticate as if holding the key.

And there's no revocation mechanism (unless you count email ).

I'm not fond of this security model.

However, you're not *entirely* at risk. This doesn't open up root access to your system, just a dedicated `nexla` user (which, if you're unpatched, could run an privilege escalation exploit to become root). They even recommend you restrict access to the two IPs listed at the top of that page, which further helps control this. (Do this!)

To better tighten things down, I'd recommend setting up a restricted shell for them that only permits the exact action they perform on your system. That way, the only thing at risk is the database they're maintaining for you.

Comment: Private key? What private key? The linked article repeatedly states this is a public keys and the steps described are those which should be applied to a public key. Public keys are so named because there disclosure does not compromise the security of communications.

Comment: @symcbean – They offer one SSH public key for two IP addresses, implying at least two hosts, each of which uses the same private key. The key's comment states it was generated on a third system, an employee's laptop. Copying *public* keys is necessary. Copying *private* keys between systems is not a good practice. If it turns out that "Avinashs-MacBook-Pro-2.local" is the server and simply has two IPs, there are much more serious issues.

Comment: You'd better tell Google that they need a unique certificate on each of their servers then.

Comment: I trust Google to have good security around the deployment of their TLS keys to their load balancers, which encrypt server-side data that is otherwise visible to Google's backend. I can't say the same about a company that clearly generates keys on employee laptops, especially when these are SSH keys that grant remote access to a myriad systems.